# import excel sheet to Guava Table

Tags: excel, apache-poi, guava

Is it possible to import excel as a guava table object where the excel sheet contains more than 3 columns?

Getting confused on this as most code samples talk about only 3 columns in sheet as seen in below link too

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/table-guava-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misinterpret the `Table<R,C,V>`. This are not three columns but `R`row, `C`olumn and `V`alue.

A `Excel` table would be a `Table<String, String, Object>` where row keys are R1, R2, R3, .. and the column keys are C1, C2, C3, ... The objects are the cell values.

When we get each cell content as `String`, then a `Excel` table would be:

```
Table<String, String, String> excelTable = HashBasedTable.create();
```

and a cell content would be put there like:

```
excelTable.put("R" + r, "C" + c, value);
```

Given an `Excel` sheet like:

[image]

The following code gets all it's content to a Guava Table.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable; 
import com.google.common.collect.Table; 

class ReadExcelToGuavaTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Table<String, String, String> excelTable = HashBasedTable.create();

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Excel.xlsx"));
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  int r = 1;
  int c = 1;
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   r = row.getRowNum() + 1;
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    c = cell.getColumnIndex() + 1;
    String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, formulaEvaluator);
    //System.out.println("R" + r + "C" + c + " = " + value);
    excelTable.put("R" + r, "C" + c, value);
   }
  }

  // get Map corresponding to row 1 in Excel 
  Map<String, String> rowMap = excelTable.row("R1"); 
  System.out.println("List of row 1 content : "); 
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> row : rowMap.entrySet()) { 
   System.out.println("Column : " + row.getKey() + ", Value : " + row.getValue()); 
  } 

  // get a Map corresponding to column 4 in Excel
  Map<String, String> columnMap = excelTable.column("C4"); 
  System.out.println("List of column 4 content : "); 
  for (Map.Entry<String, String> column : columnMap.entrySet()) { 
   System.out.println("Row : " + column.getKey() + ", Value : " + column.getValue()); 
  } 

  // get single cell content R5C5
  System.out.println("Single cell content R5C5 :"); 
  System.out.println("R5C5 : " + excelTable.get("R5", "C5")); 

  // get all rows and columns
  Map<String,Map<String,String>> allMap = excelTable.rowMap();
  System.out.println("List of whole table : "); 
  for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> row : allMap.entrySet()) { 
   Map<String, String> colMap = row.getValue();
   for (Map.Entry<String, String> column : colMap.entrySet()) { 
    System.out.println(row.getKey() + column.getKey() + " = " + column.getValue()); 
   } 
  }   

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Axel thank you for such a clear cut explanation with relevant code, appreciate it ! Many thanks!